# Did the LET statement actually do anything in 8-bit Microsoft BASICs?

Tags: applesoft-basic, basic, microsoft-basic

I know the LET statement was available in AppleSoft and other Microsoft 8-bit BASICs back in the day, but I can't think of a time where I actually used it. Frankly, I get the impression that it was supported to conform to the Dartmouth standard but the interpreter was smart enough to not require it.

Was the LET statement actually required anywhere? Were there revisions of Microsoft BASIC that actually used it? Further, if the statement *was* used, did the interpreter spend any time pondering it or did it skip right past it?

Comment: Great answers below, but tl;dr: no. In Microsoft BASIC, the LET was already completely optional. They (Bill Gates) just put it in for backward compatibility with older, non-Microsoft, standards.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that Kemeny and Kurtz were mathematicians...

Comment: Let as a statement was to make it easier for the lexical interpreter to disambiguate between a variable name at the start of a line vs. a statement.  You cannot use reserved words as variable names, and Let was one of words.  So when the interpreter read Let at the start of the line, it knew the next item was a variable.  If Let wasn't there, it would have to pattern match against reserved words first and in early interpreters, that was a performance hit.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Except for the very earliest versions of basic, `LET` was rarely used, but the `LET` keyword was *not* always optional. Early BASIC interpreters required it; however, for *most* versions that came out for the PC (including Microsoft BASIC), the use of `LET` *was* optional.

Later standards in BASIC often required that the keyword be supported, but since there was no syntactical ambiguity in leaving it out, it was included simply to ensure compatibility with previous versions of BASIC that require it.

From MSDN » [Visual BASIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/librar/aa243390%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> #### Let Statement
>
> Assigns the value of an expression to a variable or property.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> [**Let**] *varname = expression*
>
> The Let statement syntax has these parts:
>
> `Let` Optional. Explicit use of the Let keyword is a matter of style, but it is usually omitted.
> …

I've read and written quite a few BASIC interpreters way back, and the lexer definition of an  assignment statement usually looked something like this:

> *line-number* [LET] *variable* = *expression*

<sup>(line numbers were later omitted)</sup>

That means the appearance of `LET` is optional. The only time the interpreter spent in *pondering* the `LET` statement was in tokenizing the sequence of characters. But once it was parsed, the token was simply discarded. The use of `LET` didn't actually add anything in the parsing or execution of code.

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer. This is of *very* high quality, and answers the question well. I would welcome you to the site, but you've been around longer than I have.  - [From review](//retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/405)

Answer (score 22):

I can only answer to the first question: the LET statement was actually used in 48K Sinclair BASIC, in which due to the way commands are entered, a keyword is needed before an identifier can be typed, so LET was needed in order to write a variable assignment (although there were unofficial patches to the ROM that eliminated that requirement).

In fact, and while this is not a recommended practice, the use of the LET keyword allowed you to type things like this in Sinclair BASIC:

```
LET let=0
LET if i were you=2
LET i wouldnt treat me the way you do=3
```

These examples, BTW, won't work in some MS BASIC interpreters. I have try them with MSX-1.

Comment: I also remember that GFA BASIC on the Atari ST and Amiga required `LET`

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question

> *Was the LET statement actually required anywhere?*

it *was* required in ANSI standard BASIC. On [page 46](https://archive.org/details/federalinformat6821nati_0/page/46/mode/2up?q=LET) of ANSI standard X3.113-1987 "Full BASIC", the `LET` keyword is defined, and nowhere in the standard is it defined as optional. Indeed, in one of the few standard test suites for BASIC ([NBS minimal BASIC test programs](https://archive.org/details/nbsminimalbasict5007cugi/page/46/mode/2up?q=LET)), test program 185 explicitly checks for `LET` being present, and allows its omission only if suitably documented to the reviewer's satisfaction.

The program, reproduced from [ECMA-55 Minimal BASIC compiler / MB_git / [479f4b] /NBS](https://sourceforge.net/p/buraphakit/MB_git/ci/HEAD/tree/NBS/), goes as follows:

```
10 PRINT "PROGRAM FILE 185: ERROR - MISSING KEYWORD LET."
20 PRINT "    ANSI STANDARD 9.2, 9.4"
30 PRINT
40 PRINT "SECTION 185.1: ERROR - MISSING KEYWORD LET."
50 PRINT
60 PRINT "THIS IS A TEST FOR A NON-STANDARD FEATURE OF MINIMAL BASIC."
70 PRINT "TO PASS THIS TEST, THE PROCESSOR MUST EITHER:"
80 PRINT
90 PRINT "   1) ACCEPT THE PROGRAM AND BE ACCOMPANIED BY DOCUMENTATION"
100 PRINT "      ACCURATELY DESCRIBING THE FEATURE'S INTERPRETATION"
110 PRINT "      BY THE PROCESSOR, OR"
120 PRINT
130 PRINT "   2) REJECT THE PROGRAM WITH AN APPROPRIATE ERROR MESSAGE"
140 PRINT
150 PRINT "SEE THE NBS MINIMAL BASIC TEST PROGRAMS USER'S MANUAL"
160 PRINT "FOR DETAILED CRITERIA."
170 PRINT
180 PRINT "                      BEGIN TEST."
190 PRINT
200 PRINT "ABOUT TO EXECUTE 'LET X1 = 11' AND THEN 'X1 = 12'"
230 LET X1=11
240 X1=12
280 PRINT "VALUE OF X1 = ";X1
290 PRINT
300 PRINT "                        END TEST."
310 PRINT
320 PRINT "END PROGRAM 185"
330 END
```

The [BASIC-80 (MBASIC) Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/BASIC-80_MBASIC_Reference_Manual/page/n1/mode/2up?q=ansi) mentions that it is compliant, even though `LET` is optional for it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Sharp PC-1211 pocket computer (also rebranded as TRS-80 PC1 and as variants PC-1210/PC-1212) you could omit the LET keyword for simple assignments but you were required to use it in an IF statement as there was no THEN keyword (and no ELSE obviously) which would require a keyword to mark the end of boolean expression.

```
10: A=1
20: IF B=10LET A=2:GOTO 40
30: PRINT "A*B=";AB: REM * as multiplication was also optional
40: END
```

Later models based on the SC61860 ESR-H cpu (PC-12??, PC-13?0, PC-14??, etc.) added the THEN keyword but still required the LET after the THEN but only there.

EDIT: UncleBod comment added to answer

> here is an interesting reason that LET still was mandatory after THEN. If there is no keyword after THEN the following part is calculated as a line number. A=2 would result in GOTO 1 (if it was a true comparison) or GOTO 0 otherwise. Line number 1 might exist, but never line number 0. (Just tested on a PC-1262) –
> UncleBod

Comment: There is an interesting reason that LET still was mandatory after THEN. If there is no keyword after THEN the following part is calculated as a line number. A=2 would result in GOTO 1 (if it was a true comparison) or GOTO 0 otherwise. Line number 1 might exist, but never line number 0. (Just tested on a PC-1262)

Comment: Thank you. I had forgotten about that which is a shame as I had a PC-1350 and a PC-1262 for years that I still used a lot.

Answer (score -1):

When I started programming, there was only BASIC and GW BASIC followed. In those days you had to plan and reserve your memory, because there wasn't not much. LET and DIM did that trick. LET assigned memory to a variable and with DIM you had the option to define how much memory.

Comment: According to the GW-BASIC 3.2 manual, at least that version entirely ignored "LET".  I can't find any copies of the manual for older versions, but my understanding is that no version of GW-BASIC required the use of "LET".  I'm also not sure what you mean by "there was only BASIC and GW BASIC", as there were lots of different versions of BASIC around long before GW-BASIC was released in 1983.

Comment: GW BASIC was very different from the BASIC version I knew. I couldn't program in GW BASIC, because I found it a little difficult and I didn't have the special editor. I started by hacking a menu written in BASIC with the use of Ctrl-Break and LIST. And I had MS DOS, PC DOS just came on the market. I was 8 or 9 years old in that time,  do I don't recall it that precisely. I live in The Netherlands and I don't know if they released many DOS versions in Europe.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. This is a good answer, however some of the content is disputed. If you can find any, could you cite your sources please?

Comment: Wow, to find my source, I have to dig deep in my DOS/BASIC archive and maybe in an old DOS manual

Answer (score -1):

I had an old TI Basic computer (Texas Instruments) and remember always using the LET statement.  I recall that I was mostly copying BASIC programs from a textbook and since the textbook used the LET statement I did too for consistency sake.

Comment: Was TI BASIC also one (like the Sinclair one mentioned above) where you had to use LET in order to enter a variable name on the keyboard? I know it had a mapping of single keyboard key to BASIC keyword, for many keys anyway.

Comment: No, you could enter anything you wanted as a variable name on the keyboard but all the examples of TI Basic code I saw written used LET statements.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, "Was the LET statement actually required anywhere?"

Comment: "*you could enter anything you wanted as a variable name*" This is incorrect. Page 18 of the TI-99/4A BASIC Reference Manual (Howard W. Sams & Co., 1984) states that variable names have a character length limit and characters that are considered illegal.

Comment: Page 157 of the [TI-99/4A BASIC Reference Manual](https://archive.org/details/tibook_ti994a-basic-reference-manual/) (Howard W. Sams & Co., 1984) states that "You can omit the keyword LET." The book also includes program code with assignment statements that do not use the LET keyword.